# Can I use the groupby or agg to combine field contents as a list instead of as a string?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Here is my dataframe. In original data, the dates are imported as datetimes.

```
data={'Mbrshp':['A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C'], 'Level':['I','IV','IV','I','I','IV','','I'], 'Date':['2014-07-07','2017-08-09','2017-08-09','2018-07-11','2017-08-09','2017-08-09','2013-12-11','2017-08-09']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I am grouping by Mbrshp and combining the Level and Date into a field so I will have a unique record for each Mbrshp and then I want a count of how many items are in the Level field ignoring blanks.

Here is my current code.

```
df['Date']=df['Date'].astype(str) 
df['Level']=df['Level'].fillna('')

df_new=df.groupby(['Mbrshp'])['Level','Date'].agg(','.join).reset_index()
df_new['Level'] = df_new['Level'].str.split(',')
df_new['count']=df_new['Level'].str.len()
```

These are my results with my current code.

```
Mbrshp  Level   Date    count
A   ['I', 'IV'] 2014-07-07,2017-08-09   2
B   ['IV', 'I', 'I']    2017-08-09,2018-07-11,2017-08-09    3
C   ['IV', '', 'I'] 2017-08-09,2013-12-11,2017-08-09    3
```

1) I am also looking for something simpler than converting the Level field to a list separately (since the agg .join combines them into a string) and counting the length.
2) I would also like to ignore blanks when concatenating and have the count based on the number of actual items.

Thank you

Comment: What exactly do you need in the end? Do you need those lists, and then the dates string joined? Or are you just looking to get `A - 2, B - 3, C - 2`, for unique level-date combinations per member?

Comment: @ALollz I am looking for something similar to the output posted but I would like the count field to ignore the blanks in the Level field it is counting from. So yeah, I would like the lists showing too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html)

```
df.loc[df['Level']!=''].groupby('Mbrshp').agg({
    'Date': list,
    'Level': list,
    'Mbrshp': 'count'
})
```

Output:

```
                        Date                Level   Mbrshp
Mbrshp          
A   [2014-07-07, 2017-08-09]                [I, IV]     2
B   [2017-08-09, 2018-07-11, 2017-08-09]    [IV, I, I]  3
C   [2017-08-09, 2017-08-09]                [IV, I]     2
```

Comment: thank you. I would like to keep in the record even though it has a blank in the Level field. I just don'w want it in the count. With this code it is filtering that record out.

Comment: It filters it out to groupby. It does not alter your dataframe `df`. If that's what your concern is. `df.loc[df['Level']!='']` returns a copy. @Shmelky